# Changing navigation strip color with CSS

Tags: css

I own a website, Digital Phablet, i want to know how can i change thr color of Blue strip to Red? I have attached the picture too as well as you can check it on my website by typing the name on google.

Please give CSS to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file named style.css

on line 1235

```
.mobile-navbar {
    height: 44px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and on line 3824

```
.header-bottom {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It solved my problem. Is there any way I can get my type of red, like Hex Code..

Comment: I saw you already did it! :)

Comment: Yeah! it worked, thanks a lot dude.